# Sharing Rspec tests between classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

Hey all; in writing tests from controller to controller with rspec, I've found myself duplicating a few basic tests, such as this check for index:

```
describe "on GET to index" do
  it "renders the index template" do
    get :index
    response.should render_template('index')
  end
end
```

I feel that the test is important, just redundant, when added to five different controllers. Is there some way to share tests between controller classes, or include specific code blocks with a method call in rspec? Or is it best practices to duplicate, in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes [you can](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/dir/example-groups/shared-example-group), and I think it will lead to cleaner code.